# ¿porque la propiedad "data" que viene con la dependencia express-fileupload me da undefined?

Tags: nodejs, reactjs, express

Me da este error

> Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'data' of
>   undefined

Estoy usando express-fileupload para subir archivos pero me dice que la propiedad data esta indefinida, no se porque me da este error solo tengo 2 archivos en donde podria estar el problema uno es movies.js que esta en la carpeta routes y el otro es la componente uploadImages.jsx que esta en la carpeta client bajo src/components.

este es mi repositorio en github

https://github.com/Ceci007/vidly

por favor ayuda y gracias de antemano.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import http from "../services/httpService"; 
import { ToastContainer, toast } from 'react-toastify';
import Progress from './progress';
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';

class ImageUpload extends Component {
    state = {  
        movieImg: "",
        filename: "Choose File",
        uploadedFile: {},
        uploadPercentage: 0
    }

    onImageChange = e => {
        console.log(e.target.files[0].name);

        this.setState({ 
            movieImg: e.target.files[0], 
            filename: e.target.files[0].name
        });
    }

    onSubmit = async e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("movieImg", this.state.movieImg);

        
        const res = await http.post("http://localhost:3900/api/movies/img", formData, {
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
            },
            onUploadProgress: progressEvent => {
                this.setState({
                    uploadPercentage: (parseInt(Math.round((progressEvent.loaded*100)/progressEvent.total)))
                });

                setTimeout(() => this.setState({uploadPercentage : 0}), 5000);
            }               
        })
        .then(res => { toast.success('upload success') })
        .catch(err => { toast.error('upload fail') });

        const { filename, filepath } = res.data; // el error viene de aquí
        this.setState({ uploadedFile: {filename, filepath }});
    }

    render() { 
        return (  
            <div>
                <div className="form-group">
                <ToastContainer />
                </div>
                <form onSubmit = {this.onSubmit}>
                <div className="custom-file mb-4">
                    <input name="movieImg" type="file" className="custom-file-input" id="customFile" onChange={this.onImageChange} />
                    <label className="custom-file-label" htmlFor="customFile" >
                        {this.state.filename}
                    </label>
                </div>
                <Progress percentage={this.state.uploadPercentage} />
                <input type="submit" value="Upload" className="btn btn-primary btn-block mt-4" />
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
 
export default ImageUpload;
```

Este es el codigo del servidor.

```js
router.post("/img", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req);
  if(Object.keys(req.files).length == 0) {
    return res.status(400).send("No files were uploaded.");
  }

  let movieImg = req.files.movieImg;
  movieImg.mv(`${__dirname}/client/public/img/${movieImg.name}`, err => {
    if(err) {
      return res.status(500).send(err);
    }

    res.json({ filename: movieImg.name, filepath: `/img/${movieImg.name}` });
  });
});
```

y aqui inicializo el paquete express-fileupload.

```js
const winston = require("winston");
const express = require("express");
const fileupload = require("express-fileupload");
const config = require("config");
const app = express();

app.use(fileupload());
```

Answer (score 1):

El error  ocurre porque el `await` **consume** la promesa pero hay una cadena detrás que tiene un `then` que modifica el valor resultante que se asigna a `res.

Tienes 2 opciones:
1. Eliminas la cadena
2. Propagas el valor para que llegue a tu variable de todas formas

La primera solución sería

```
try {
    const res = await http.post("http://localhost:3900/api/movies/img", formData, {
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
        },
        onUploadProgress: progressEvent => {
            this.setState({
                uploadPercentage: (parseInt(Math.round((progressEvent.loaded*100)/progressEvent.total)))
            });

            setTimeout(() => this.setState({uploadPercentage : 0}), 5000);
        }               
    });
    toast.success('upload success');
    const { filename, filepath } = res.data; // res es el valor que esperas
} catch (e) {
    toast.error('upload fail')
}
```

Propagar el valor sería

```
.then(res => { toast.success('upload success'); return res; })
```

si no propagas el valor el then retorna `undefined` y `undefined` no puede tener una propiedad `data`.

Comment: me sigue diciendo lo mismo error 500 y data undefined pero tu codigo es mas limpio que el mio asique lo usare, gracias!

Comment: @CeciResponde Si estás usando la primera variante pues no te puede decir que data undefined porque nunca llegaría allí. En el caso de propagacion pues claro que si falla lo que viene es un error y seguro que `data` en el error es `undefined`. El error ocurre en el server y lo que pones aquí es el código del cliente.

Comment: si deberia agregar más información voy a editar

Comment: ya esta lo edite, la verdad cuando tengo un solo archivo para el servidor es decir en un proyecto chico solo de subir una imagen si me funcionaba asique capaz sea el lugar donde estoy inicializando el fileupload no?

Comment: @CeciResponde Te da error 500 porque req.files no está definido. Creo que deberías usar un framework de multipart/form-data como [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer)